# How to show SObject fields in a visual workflow?

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow, flow

I want to show some standard fields, of the Case standard object, in a visual workflow.

Anyone has a workaround for this?

I have tried, to set them as a SObject Variable, but I don't know which type of assignment to perform, to give them the right value.

Note: I have already linked the case with the visual workflow, through a variable CaseId.

Edit: I am editing the post to give further dettails. 
- The first screenshot is the layout of visual workflow.
- The second screenshot is the first screen of the Visual Workflow(properties window).

SShot 1: 
[image]

SShot 2: 
[image]

*Goal: Is to visualize in the layout of the Visual Workflow, some info of the Parent case, from where the flow was called.

Comment: Can you show us a screen capture of your visual flow or what you'd like it do? Your question is difficult to answer in the way that it's phrased. You can assign the Id to the Id field of an sObject Variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have updated the question with further dettails.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Do you have a flow diagram from the flow builder showing how you want your flow to work? You can drag elements onto the builder that represent each one to create a flowchart. Alternatively, you might want to go to https://www.gliffy.com/ and use their free utility to create a flowchart of how you want your flow to work.

Comment: I don't think that there is the need for that, since I am pretty familiar with the basic functionalities of the Visual Workflow. I just need some instructions which feature to use in dettail, or which component. Still, I am uploading that view too. 
Thanks!

Comment: Its very difficult to try and help someone with a flow. Have you been through the [Trailhead Process Automation Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/business_process_automation) that covers Visual Flows? You might find that helpful in getting yourself sorted. There's also [The Power of Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/en/events/webinars/power_of_flow) webinars that would be good resources for you if you're not finding what you need in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the resources! I think I am going to study them. 
Wish you well.

Comment: You're very welcome. I couldn't garner enough info from your screen captures to tell what you needed. I know it's difficult to describe your issue with a flow and I just wasn't "getting it". I've seen those webinars and they're very well done. Have also done the Trailhead modules too which I think you'll find helpful too even though they're not very advanced.